# How to resolve table view jerk while removing a row and simultaneously adding a new row and scrolling to it?

Tags: swift, uitableview, user-interface

Does any one know how can i support these two operations simultaneously using table view in UIKit, without any UI Glitches ?

1. Removal of a table view row
2. Addition of a table view row at end of table view and scrolling to that row.

The issue i am facing is a UI Glitch that is annoying and want to get rid of it. You can see the Glitch in this [attached](https://vimeo.com/665631679) video.

---

### Demo application

I have made a simple demo app. Code can be found in this [Github](https://github.com/AwaisFayyaz/tableView-add-delete-glitch) repo.

So in this demo app, i am removing the first row from table (with batch updates) with a timer of 2 seconds.

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { timer in
      
      if self.scrollInProgress { return }
      self.removalInProgress = true
      let updates = {

        let rowToDelete = 0
        self.updatedArray.remove(at: rowToDelete)
        let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: rowToDelete, section: 0)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
      }
      let completion = { (success: Bool) in
        self.removalInProgress = false
        print("completion")
      }
      self.tableView.performBatchUpdates(updates, completion: completion)
    }
```

And the send button just adds another row at bottom of table and scrolls to it.

```
@IBAction func btnSendTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let searchText = fieldSendMessage.text, !searchText.isEmpty else {
      return
    }
    
    updatedArray.append(searchText)
    tableView.reloadData()
    scrollToBottom()
    messsageSendingCounter += 1
    fieldSendMessage.text = "\(messsageSendingCounter)"
  }
```

So when the addition of row at the bottom and removal of row from the top happens at same time, the table view jerks which i need to avoid.

I have tried to make use of flags to try to run one of the two tasks at one time but still, the glitch is there. And also, i am not sure if this is a good solution.

Thanks in advance for any hints/suggestions to solve this problem.

Comment: Actually, send action hits scroll animation. Either the animation should be cancelled when send action performs, or send shouldn't do anything until animation finishes 100%.